# Как в питоне разделить VVKVKK на V V K V K K

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в питоне разделить VVKVKK на V V K V K K

Comment: `print(" ".join("VVKVKK"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = "VVKVKK"
s = " ".join(s)
```

Если надо просто вывести, то можно так:

```
print(*s)
```

Answer (score 0):

если надо разделить в строке, то надо просто пересобрать

```
text_new = ' '.join(text_old)
```

а если при выводе на экран, то есть варианты:

```
print(*text, sep=' ')
```

впрочем для пробела `sep=' '` можно и опустить